# Dynamic array contains junk in first 3 columns of first row

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a program which so far is taking in 4 values 1st is the case, 2nd is basically how many columns, the 3rd value doesn't matter right now and the last value specifies rows.

For some reason when I enter  4 6 4 the program will out put the grid of 0's fine.
When I do 7 6 4, the first 3 columns in the first row contain large nonsense numbers.
When I do 4 6 7 it blatantly crashes.
When I do 8 6 4 the problem is in the first row first 4 columns.
I have no idea what the problem is but I think its somewhere in my 2nd calloc call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int** makeArray();
int permute();


int main()
{   int cases, slotsToFill, possibleColors,movesMade;
    int i;
    int j;
    int** moves;

    scanf("%d", &cases);
    for( i = 0; i < cases; i++){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &slotsToFill,&possibleColors,&movesMade);
        moves = makeArray(movesMade,slotsToFill);
    }
    /*for(i = 0; i < movesMade; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<slotsToFill; j++){
            printf(" %d", moves[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/
 system("pause");
    return 0;

}

int** makeArray(int rows, int cols){
    int** moves;
    int i;
    int j;
    cols = cols + 2;
    moves = calloc(rows,sizeof(int*));
    if(moves != NULL){
        for(i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            moves[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(int));
            if(moves[i]== NULL){
                printf("ALLOCATION FAILED\n");
                break;
            }

        }
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            printf(" %d", moves[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    }


    return moves;
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 this was the solution  thank you and it makes sense now that I realize it.